# Why do I get NullReferenceException here?

Tags: c#, exception, nullreferenceexception

I have:

```
partial class StarSystem : AstroThreeNode
{
    public static StarSystem SunSolarSystem()
    {
        return new StarSystem("Solar System", Planet.SunCenter(), Resources.Space, SolarSystem.ActiveForm.Bounds).AddPlanet(Planet.MercuryPlanet(), Planet.VenusPlanet(), Planet.EarthPlanet(), Planet.MarsPlanet(), Planet.JupiterPlanet(), Planet.SaturnPlanet(), Planet.UranusPlanet(), Planet.NeptunePlanet());
    }

    public StarSystem AddPlanet(params Planet[] planetsToAdd)
    {
        foreach (Planet planet in planetsToAdd)
        {
            distanceFromSun += (planets.Count > 0 ? planets[planets.Count - 1].Image.Width / 2 : 0) + planet.Image.Width / 2 + DISTANCE_BETWEEN_PLANETS;
            planet.DistanceFromSun = distanceFromSun;
            planet.RotationCenter = new PointF(bounds.Width / 2, bounds.Height / 2);
            planets.Add(planet);
        }
        return this;
    }
}


partial class Planet : AstroThreeNode
{
    private const float SUN_SPEED = 0;
    public static Planet SunCenter() 
    {
        return new Planet("Слънце", Resources.Sun_, SUN_SPEED, CLOCKWISE);
    }
    public static Planet MercuryPlanet()
    {
        return new Planet("Меркурий", Resources.Mercury_, 4.0923f, Planet.CLOCKWISE);
    }
    public static Planet VenusPlanet()
    {
        return new Planet("Венера", Resources.Venus_, 1.6021f, Planet.COUNTERCLOCKWISE);
    }
    public static Planet EarthPlanet()
    {
        return new Planet("Земя", Resources.Earth_, 0.9856f, Planet.CLOCKWISE);
    }
    public static Planet MarsPlanet()
    {
        return new Planet("Марс", Resources.Mars_, 0.5240f, Planet.CLOCKWISE);
    }
    public static Planet JupiterPlanet()
    {
        return new Planet("Юпитер", Resources.Jupiter_, 0.0830f, Planet.CLOCKWISE);
    }
    public static Planet SaturnPlanet()
    {
        return new Planet("Сатурн", Resources.Saturn_, 0.0334f, Planet.CLOCKWISE);
    }
    public static Planet UranusPlanet()
    {
        return new Planet("Уран", Resources.Uranus_, 0.0117f, Planet.COUNTERCLOCKWISE);
    }
    public static Planet NeptunePlanet() 
    {
        return new Planet("Нептун", Resources.Neptune_, 0.0059f, Planet.CLOCKWISE);
    }

    public Planet(string name, Image image, float distanceFromSun, float degreesAddedEachTick, bool clockwise, PointF rotationCenter, float angleInDegrees = 0)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Image = image; // here I set the Image but I get an exception later
        this.DistanceFromSun = distanceFromSun;
        this.degreesAddedEachTick = degreesAddedEachTick;
        this.isClockwiseRotation = clockwise;
        this.RotationCenter = rotationCenter;
        this.angleInDegrees = angleInDegrees;
    }
}
```

I get the exception here: `distanceFromSun += (planets.Count > 0 ? planets[planets.Count - 1].Image.Width / 2 : 0) + planet.Image.Width / 2 + DISTANCE_BETWEEN_PLANETS;`
For the `planet.Image`. I don't get it why do I get exception when I set the Image when I create a `Planet`.

**EDIT:** Here is the constructor for `StarSystem` :

```
    public StarSystem(string name, Planet starSystemCenter, Image background, Rectangle bounds)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Background = background;
        this.bounds = bounds;
        planets = new List<Planet>(); //planets instanieted here
        planets.Add(starSystemCenter); // note I dont get the exception on this call but on the other call where I add all other planest
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**
Found my problem but I have to go to bed I will post the answer tomorrow.

Comment: If you need more code tell me here in the comments

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: @JohnSaunders I would highly doubt that since almost all nullreferences are different.

Comment: @John Saunders There is a difference between What is a _____ exception and Why am I getting _____ exception. You can understand what an exception is for but not understand or know what part of your code is the cause of it.

Comment: @LaurenceBurke, and yet the answer is generally the same.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint after the line that sets Planet.Image, is Image null?

Comment: @LaurenceBurke: Quite the reverse: every NullReferenceException has the same cause, and the steps taken to diagnose it are generally the same too.

Comment: @JonSkeet so yes they will be similar but not duplicate. Therefore different

Comment: @jmein: did you read the linked question and its answers? It's about both the causes and the fixes.

Comment: @sq33G Wow it didn't execute the Image property.

Comment: @LaurenceBurke: sorry, I totally disagree. Every case of, "I didn't set it, then I used it" is the exact same mistake. The linked question shows many different examples of this, to make it easier to recognize them by sight.

Comment: Does the other side of the Planet class have a constructor that takes only 4 arguments?

Comment: @LaurenceBurke: I don't buy that - it's sufficiently similar, that if the OP reads through the linked question, they're likely to be able to  work out their own answer.

Comment: @sq33G Yes it has `public Planet(string name, Image image, float degreesAddedEachTick, bool clockwise){...}`

Comment: ...does a breakpoint put in there get hit?

Comment: @sq33G Yes it got hit but I got surprised when I set the `Image` the `image` parameter was not null but when the `this.Image = Image` got ex....Wait a sec..FOUND MY PROB!! I am doing `this.Image = Image` and not `this.Image = image`

Comment: @JohnSaunders et al. **Bad Naming Convention**?

Comment: @LaurenceBurke: Notice the similarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to have class members, local variables, and method parameters differ by more than capitalization. See **Bad Naming Convention** in the canonical NullReferenceException post linked above.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're never instantiating your 'Planets' object (probably a `List<Planet>`?)

Is it in your `StarSystem` code?

Presumably it would be something like

```
public class StarSystem
{
    public List<Planet> planets {get; set;}
    //Other code here

    public StarSystem()
    {
        planets = new List<Planet>();
    }
}
```

But that code is not in evidence in your post.  That's what I find to be the most likely culprit.

Post Question Edit:
Okay, then the only thing that seems to leave is the `.Image` for one or more of your planets.  When you debug, you should be able to watch your variables- I would set a break-point before it evaluates that expression, and look at the last object it added, and the next object it's going to try to add, and look for a null `.Image`

Comment: I am instancing everything I don't understand what are you talking about

Comment: @Bosak - Where is your line where `Planets` is instantiated?  `var Planets = ???`

Comment: He's talking about `planets.Count`.  He doesn't think `planets` was initialized.

Comment: @DMoses: that's what I think, too.

Comment: But I'm sure that `planets` is initalised

Comment: @Bosak - How?  There's nothing in your code that references 'planets' until the line `planets.Add(planet);`

Comment: @AllenG I edited the question and added the `StarSystem` constructor

Comment: I except that the problem may be that the planet creator methods are static and something is not getting executed there. Maybe its because `Image` has a default value of `null`, but I still cant find where is the error

Answer (score 0):

You create each planet with this constructor

```
public Planet(string name, Image image, float distanceFromSun, float degreesAddedEachTick, bool clockwise, PointF rotationCenter, float angleInDegrees = 0)
```

Yet you never check to make sure that `image != null && image.Width != null`  (if width is a native int you don't need to, but if it is a `Number` you do need that check.

Comment: It is a native int. I get the exception for the image not for the with .

Comment: Then i suggest putting a `if (image == null) throw new  IllegalArgumentException();` in the Planet constructor.  See if that gives you a different error.  Should be able to tell who is setting a null image.

Comment: No it gives the same exception

Comment: Then you are doing 1 of two things: not actually using that costructor... i noticed you use a constructor with 4 parameters?  Or you change the image member variable to null after it is instantiated.